# python: invalid syntax on a for loop when everything is correct

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

Python keeps telling me invalid syntax

```
In [7]:   File "/tmp/ipython-4302iuN.py", line 26
    for n in N:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The reason it occurs on line 26 and I don't have 26 lines here is due to the shebang line and comments.

```
L = 80.0                                               
N = 2 ** np.arange(0, 10, dtype = np.float64)
dt = 0.0002
tmax = 10
nmax = int(np.floor(tmax / dt))  #  also try ceil/floor                            

deltax = []
error = []
u = 2. * (2. / (np.exp(x + 20.) + np.exp(-x - 20.)) ** 2


for n in N:
    dx = L / n
```

I have tried using range with integers as a test.  I opened a separate ipython and ran

```
for n in range(1, 2):
    dx = 10 / n
```

which worked just fine.

What is wrong with the syntax?

I have closed python and re-opened but that didn't help either.

Comment: You forgot brackets on `u = 2. *`, and what on earth is `np`?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: `np` is the standard abbreviation used when importing the `numpy` library.  Often you'll see `import numpy as np` at the start of numerical programs.

Comment: "When is everything is correct" -> That's the reason why it's working perfectly!
Otherwise, the shebang is still counted as one line (it would be so confusing if it wasn't).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When faced with a mysterious syntax error, always look above:

```
>>> s = "u = 2. * (2. / (np.exp(x + 20.) + np.exp(-x - 20.)) ** 2"
>>> s.count("(")
4
>>> s.count(")")
3
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add an ending bracket here

```
u = 2. * (2. / (np.exp(x + 20.) + np.exp(-x - 20.)) ** 2)
                                                        ^
```

On top of that you have not defined `x` here:

```
u = 2. * (2. / (np.exp(x + 20.) + np.exp(-x - 20.)) ** 2)
```